# Comparing multiple numeric vectors by ranks

Tags: classification, multiple-comparisons

I've been recently looking into multiple classifier comparison, and it seems the works of Demsar (2008) remain state-of-the-art in this field.

Let $u_1$,$u_2$ and $u_3$ represent three real valued vectors corresponding to e.g., accuracy scores across multiple datasets (size of the vectors).

Currently, Friedman's test with Nemenyi post-hoc corrections was suggested, however, this test only considers ranks, but not e.g., absolute differences in performance (i.e. scale)

Are there any statistical tests that indeed, when offering multiple classifier comparisons, also consider the values of what is being compared and not only ranks? Why is this possible/impossible?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't really understand the context of the question, but one non-rank-based test for an unreplicated complete block design would be a traditional anova with a main factor variable, a blocking variable, and no interaction.

Comment: The context is general machine learning evaluation. Could you please link to the example you mention?